# Word2vec/SkipGram: Why softmax?

Tags: neural-networks, word-embeddings, word2vec, softmax

In Word2Vec (SkipGram version), there is a softmax layer at the end of the neural net. As this is expansive to calculate, some approximations are used instead, such as negative sampling.

But if in the end of the day we will only care about the weights in the first layer (the embeddings), why do we bother using a softmax at all? Couldn't we just use raw outputs instead?

Comment: To whoever flagged this as belonging on Stack Overflow instead—no, this question is not about programming and debugging.

Comment: Which “raw outputs” are you talking about?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy The outputs of the hidden layer, before the softmax function turning them into a probability.

Comment: So now you have a real-number scalar for each word. What would you compare it to? In other words—what would your objective function be?

Comment: Can't I still calculate the error of this output vector against my ground truth as usual? For example, in a 3-word vocabulary, my prediction pred = [12.7, 5, 3219] and my ground truth y = [0, 1, 0]. Can't I just do (y - pred) and backpropagate the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross entropy loss by Softmax is a loss function. If you try [0, 1, 0] and do (y-pred) you would use another loss function.

Why not just 0 and 1?

> Sometimes, the loss function we actually care about (say, classiﬁcation error) is not one that can be optimized eﬃciently. For example, exactly minimizing expected 0-1 loss is typically intractable (exponential in the input dimension), even for a linear classiﬁer (Marcotte and Savard, 1992). In such situations, one typically optimizes a surrogate loss function instead, which acts as a proxy but has advantages. For example, the negative log-likelihood of the correct class is typically used as asurrogate for the 0-1 loss. The negative log-likelihood allows the model to estimate the conditional probability of the classes, given the input, and if the model can do that well, then it can pick the classes that yield the least classiﬁcation error inexpectation.

Reference:

8.1.2 of the [deeplearningbook](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html).